# how to change boolean value given in generics view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to change the default value(false) to true when the url is triggered 
when the user enter 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/message/read/2'
I want that the message with id 2 will be change its isRead value to True.

Model

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    isRead = models.BooleanField('read status', default=False)
```

urls.py

```
path('message/read/<int:pk>/', ReadMessageView.as_view(), name='read_already'),
```

views.py- (not sure what to do here...)

```
class ReadMessageView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MessageReadSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the ListCreateAPIView class it will call the list function on the get (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L238). And if you then look at the list (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L37) function it will filter the queryset with filter_queryset, so you can extends this function and update the isRead for all objects in the queryset.

Maybe not the nicest place for on update, but it's an easy hook in.

```py
def filter_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
  queryset = super().filter_queryset(*args, **kwargs)

  # Do your update on queryset

  return queryset
```